# Sorting DataFrame by column values to match a specific list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

I would like to sort a DataFrame by column values, so that this column would match a certain list of values.

For example I have following DataFrame:

```
> df[0] 
0            1
1            2
2            4
3            5
4            8
5            15
```

and my list of values is following:

```
> list_of_values
[1, 15, 8, 5, 2, 4]
```

Is there any explicit way of doing this in Pandas? I've tried using .sort_values(), but "key" argument works differently from what I've expected.

Thank you in advance.

Best regards.

Is there any explicit way of doing this in Pandas? I've tried using .sort_values(), but "key" argument works differently from what I've expected.

Thank you in advance.

Best regards.

Comment: Use a Categorical. You could use `key` but that would be more hacky